# How to import and transpile es6 modules in an Angular build without "ejecting"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want to import a module from my `node_modules` directory that has modern Javascript syntax (e.g. nullish coalescing operators) but Angular CLI's managed webpack configuration does not provide for this and produces errors like "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" with a snippet from the code where it failed, the line with the problem using modern ES syntax.

I've tried adding a [custom builder](https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21), but I couldn't manage to get it working.

Ideally, I'd like the import to be transpiled via babel and whatever other build steps Angular uses under the hood.

Is this possible without "ejecting" the Angular CLI configuration?